# Раскрыть или скрыть список

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый вечер!

Помогите разобраться, как сделать, чтобы при раскрытии списка, остальные **div**(ы) которые ниже раскрывающегося **div**(а) смещались все вниз ровно одной линией, а не уходили куда попало...

```
<div class="sportp"><div class="box">Раскрыть 1 <span class="expand">+</span></div>
    <ul class="ulSport">
    <li><a href="<?=PATH?>category/<?=$key?>"> Тест 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=PATH?>category/<?=$key?>"> Тест 2</a>   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="sportp"><div class="box">Раскрыть 1 <span class="expand">+</span></div>
    <ul class="ulSport">
    <li><a href="<?=PATH?>category/<?=$key?>"> Тест 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=PATH?>category/<?=$key?>"> Тест 2</a>   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
.
.
.
.
```

Пример [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/a5zzgnja/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такие стили для класса "sportp":

```
.sportp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 153px;
    margin: 20px 0 0px 43px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно:)